# Modificar Register asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net

por favor necesito saber como modificar el inicio de sesión automático al momento de registrar el usuario, soy nuevo en esto y bueno ahorita registra pero se inicia sesión y quisiera que solo me registre y si va a acceder que se dirija al formulario de inicio de sesión.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de ante mano. saludes..

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, para que conozcas como usar el sitio haz el [recorrido de inicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), Podrías ayudarnos agregando el código y no una imagen, facilita las respuestas. También si agregaras un poco más de tu código ayudaría bastante

Answer (score 0):

Me falta mas contexto del codigo pero si quieres que se redirija a supongamos ~/Home.aspx agregando un boton y un metodo alcanza. Adentro podrías agregar la logica para que verifique si el usuario esta en tu base.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
}
```